# ContentProvider, issues with update and delete requests

Tags: java, android, android-contentprovider

I began to study the mechanism *ContentProvider* I decided to write a simple example, when one application uses the data of another. My goal is to implement update, delete, and insert requests to the database.

I wrote the provider and the provider's client, insert is working, but update and delete requests applies to the entire table, rather than to a specific record.

I can't understand, what am I doing wrong?

Here is my provider:

```
public class MyProvider extends ContentProvider {

final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";

static final String DB_NAME = "mydb";
static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

static final String CONTACT_TABLE = "_id";
static final String CONTACT_id = "_id";
static final String CONTACT_NAME = "name";
static final String CONTACT_EMAIL = "email";

static final String DB_CREATE = "create table "+CONTACT_TABLE+"("+
        CONTACT_id+" integer primary key autoincrement,"+
        CONTACT_NAME+ " text,"+
        CONTACT_EMAIL+" text);";

static final String AUTHORITY = "com.dandewine.user.contentprovider.AddressBook";
static final String CONTACT_PATH = "contacts";

public static final Uri CONTACT_CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://"+AUTHORITY+"/"+CONTACT_PATH);
static final String CONTACT_CONTENT_TYPE = "vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd."+AUTHORITY+"."+CONTACT_PATH;
static  final int URI_CONTACT = 1;
static final int URI_CONTACT_ID = 2;

private static final UriMatcher uriMatcher;
static{
    uriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
    uriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, CONTACT_PATH, URI_CONTACT);
    uriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, CONTACT_PATH + "/#", URI_CONTACT);
}

DBHelper helper;
SQLiteDatabase db;
@Override
public boolean onCreate(){
    Log.d(LOG_TAG,"onCreate");
    helper = new DBHelper(getContext());
    return true;
}

@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG,"query, "+uri.toString());
    switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)){
        case URI_CONTACT:
            Log.d(LOG_TAG,"URI_CONTACTS");
            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(sortOrder))
                sortOrder=CONTACT_NAME+" ASC";
            break;
        case URI_CONTACT_ID:
            String id = uri.getLastPathSegment();
            Log.d(LOG_TAG,"URI_CONTACTS_ID,"+id);
            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(selection))
                selection=CONTACT_id+" = "+id;
            else
                selection=selection+" AND "+CONTACT_id+" = "+id;
            break;
        default:throw new IllegalArgumentException("Wrong URI: "+uri);
    }
    db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(CONTACT_TABLE,projection,selection,selectionArgs,null,null,sortOrder);
    cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(),CONTACT_CONTENT_URI);
    return cursor;
}

@Override
public String getType(Uri uri) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "getType, " + uri.toString());
    switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)) {
        case URI_CONTACT:
            return CONTACT_CONTENT_TYPE;
        case URI_CONTACT_ID:
            return CONTACT_CONTENT_TYPE;
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG,"insert, "+uri.toString());
    if(uriMatcher.match(uri)!=URI_CONTACT)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Wrong URI: "+uri);
    db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    long rowID = db.insert(CONTACT_TABLE,null,values);
    Uri resultURI = ContentUris.withAppendedId(CONTACT_CONTENT_URI,rowID);
    getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(resultURI,null);
    return resultURI;
}

@Override
public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG,"delete, "+uri.toString());
    switch(uriMatcher.match(uri)){
        case URI_CONTACT:
            Log.d(LOG_TAG,"URI_CONTACT");
            break;
        case URI_CONTACT_ID:
            String id = uri.getLastPathSegment();
            Log.d(LOG_TAG,"URI_CONTACTS_ID, "+id);
            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(selection))
                selection=CONTACT_id+" = "+id;
            else
                selection = selection + " AND "+CONTACT_id+" = "+id;
            break;
        default:throw new IllegalArgumentException("Wrong URI: "+uri);
    }
    db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    int cnt = db.delete(CONTACT_TABLE,selection,selectionArgs);
    getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri,null);
    return cnt;
}

@Override
public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "update, " + uri.toString());
    switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)) {
        case URI_CONTACT:
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "URI_CONTACTS");

            break;
        case URI_CONTACT_ID:
            String id = uri.getLastPathSegment();
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "URI_CONTACTS_ID, " + id);
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(selection)) {
                selection = CONTACT_id + " = " + id;
            } else {
                selection = selection + " AND " + CONTACT_id + " = " + id;
            }
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Wrong URI: " + uri);
    }
    db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    int cnt = db.update(CONTACT_TABLE, values, selection, selectionArgs);
    getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
    return cnt;
}
private class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(DB_CREATE);
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        for (int i = 0; i <=3 ; i++) {
            cv.put(CONTACT_NAME,"name "+i);
            cv.put(CONTACT_EMAIL,"email "+i);
            db.insert(CONTACT_TABLE,null,cv);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
}
```

Here is client app:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>,
    View.OnClickListener {

final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";
static final Uri CONTACT_URI = Uri.parse("content://com.dandewine.user.contentprovider.AddressBook/contacts");
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
final String CONTACT_NAME = "name";
final String CONTACT_EMAIL = "email";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    String from[] = {"name","email"};
    int to[] = {android.R.id.text1,android.R.id.text2};
    adapter =new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,null,from,to,0);
    ListView lvContact = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvContact);
    lvContact.setAdapter(adapter);
    getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0,null,this);

}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG,"onClick");
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    Uri uri;
    int count;
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.btnInsert:
            cv.put(CONTACT_EMAIL,"email 4");
            cv.put(CONTACT_NAME,"name 4");
            uri = getContentResolver().insert(CONTACT_URI,cv);
            Log.d(LOG_TAG,"insert, result Uri: "+uri.toString());
            Toast.makeText(this,"Insert",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.btnDelete:
            uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(CONTACT_URI,3);
            count = getContentResolver().delete(uri,null,null);
            Log.d(LOG_TAG,"delete, count = "+count);
            Toast.makeText(this,"Delete",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.btnUpdate:
            cv.put(CONTACT_NAME,"name 5");
            cv.put(CONTACT_EMAIL,"email 5");
            uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(CONTACT_URI,2);
            count = getContentResolver().update(uri,cv,null,null);
            Log.d(LOG_TAG,"update, count ="+count);
            Toast.makeText(this,"Update",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.btnError:
            Toast.makeText(this,"Error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            uri = Uri.parse("content://com.dandewine.user.contentprovider.AddressBook/phones");
            try{
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri,null,null,null,null);
            }catch (Exception ex){
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Error: " + ex.getClass() + ", " + ex.getMessage());
            }
            break;
    }
    getSupportLoaderManager().getLoader(0).forceLoad();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {
    return new MyLoader(this,CONTACT_URI);
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
    adapter.swapCursor(cursor);
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {

}

private static class MyLoader extends android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader{
    Uri uri;
    public MyLoader(Context context,Uri uri) {
        super(context,uri,null, null, null, null);
        this.uri=uri;
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor loadInBackground() {
        return getContext().getContentResolver().query(uri,null,null,null,null);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I found, it was stupid mistake in UriMatcher I add two identical id